# C++ Recursively searching for files with certain extensions

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, recursion, visual-c++

I'm trying to write a function to take an `std::set` of file extensions, and recursively search for files with any of those extensions, writing the paths to a file:

```
auto get_files(_In_ const std::wstring root, // root dir of search
        _In_ const std::set<std::string> &ext, // extensions to search for)
        _Out_ std::wofstream &ret /* file to write paths to */) -> int
{
    HANDLE find = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    // check root path
    {
        LPCWSTR root_path = root.c_str();
        DWORD root_attrib = GetFileAttributesW(root_path);
        if(root_attrib == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) return 1; // root doesn't exist
        if(!(root_attrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) return 2; // root isn't a directory
    }

    LPCWSTR dir;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW fd;

    // dir concat
    {
        std::wstring x = root.c_str();
        x.append(L"\\*");
        dir = x.c_str();
    }


    find = FindFirstFileW(dir, &fd);

    do {
        if(fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) // current file is a dir
            get_files(dir, ext, ret);
        else {
            LPCWSTR current_ext = PathFindExtensionW(fd.cFileName);
            if(ext.find(current_ext) != ext.end()) {
                ret << fd.cFileName << '\n';
            }
        }
    } while (FindNextFileW(find, &fd) != 0);

    FindClose(find);

    return 0;

}
```

I get the following errors:

> E0304 no instance of overloaded function "std::set<_Kty, _Pr, _Alloc>::find [with _Kty=std::string, _Pr=std::less, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list

and this .

> C2664 'std::_Tree_const_iterator>> std::_Tree>::find(const std::basic_string,std::allocator> &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const wchar_t *' to 'const std::basic_string,std::allocator> &'

Comment: The second error says it all: `cannot convert argument 1 from 'const wchar_t *' to (the worked out version of) std::string`.

Comment: Also note that `dir` points to the contents of a `std::wstring` that was destroyed. If this works it is only by accident.

Comment: You cannot compare `std::string`s with `std::wstring`s. Therefore either convert your `std::wstring` filename to a `std::string`, or use a `std::set` of `std::wstring`s. Your option. And unless you fix that undefined behavior with using a pointer to a deleted `std::string`, be prepared to deal with random, unpredictable, mysterious bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. Type conflict between `std::set<std::string> &ext` and `LPCWSTR current_ext`. You can use `std::set<std::wstring> &ext` to solve your the E0304 error.
2. As @Botje pointed out, note the `std::wstring x` working scope. You can remove the outside brace.

The following code compiled successfully for me. Please have a check:

```
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <set>
#include <fstream>

auto get_files(_In_ const std::wstring root, // root dir of search
    _In_ const std::set<std::wstring> &ext, // extensions to search for)
    _Out_ std::wofstream &ret /* file to write paths to */) -> int
{
    HANDLE find = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    // check root path
    {
        LPCWSTR root_path = root.c_str();
        DWORD root_attrib = GetFileAttributesW(root_path);
        if (root_attrib == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) return 1; // root doesn't exist
        if (!(root_attrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) return 2; // root isn't a directory
    }

    LPCWSTR dir;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW fd;

    // dir concat
    std::wstring x = root.c_str();
    x.append(L"\\*");
    dir = x.c_str();

    find = FindFirstFileW(dir, &fd);

    do {
        if (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) // current file is a dir
            get_files(dir, ext, ret);
        else {
            LPCWSTR current_ext = PathFindExtensionW(fd.cFileName);
            if (ext.find(current_ext) != ext.end()) {
                ret << fd.cFileName << '\n';
            }
        }
    } while (FindNextFileW(find, &fd) != 0);

    FindClose(find);

    return 0;
}
```

As for second error `C2664` I can't reproduce it. Make sure you post the exact code that reproduce these two error to you.